# Rails routing: How to show /users/:id/posts/:id as /posts/:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am working on a basic rails app and wondering how do I show `/users/:id/posts/:id as /posts/:id`. Right now my routes is

```
resources :users do
  resources :post
 end
```

Which i need to have so that every post gets associated by the user. But also at the same time for ease of use, i need to be able to show the post at `/posts/:id`

Any help of suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a second route to the same controller:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

resources :posts
```

You just need to handle not having a user_id parameter in your posts controller gracefully.

Comment: I would advocate adding `except: [:show]` to the first one, and `only: [:index, :show]` on the second.

Comment: awesome, instead of index, i was using main. But yes it did it. thanks @thomasfedb :)

Comment: @psharam `index` would be considered far more conventional than `main`.

Answer (score 2):

you probably looking for **shallow** option in Rails

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :post
end
```

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/11-needless-deep-nesting

Comment: it actually worked for me, what's your db structure? and please post your rake routes results